# vb.net taking too much time to load user control containing Label control array

Tags: vb.net, vb6-migration

I am **upgrading** user control from vb6 to vb.net.
In the vb6 application I am loading 3000 labels using a label control array.
In vb.net I am doing same but it's taking too much time to load.
In vb6 it's taking 1-2 seconds, but in vb.net it's taking 30-40 seconds for same work.
What is problem? Why does it take too much time in vb.net for same work?

Code is given below, here `Led` is the label control array.

```
For l = 1 To 3000
  Led.Load(ledCounter)
  ColLed.Add(Led(ledCounter))
  Led(ledCounter).BackColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromOle(LedColor)
  Led(ledCounter).Top = VB6.TwipsToPixelsY(15)
  Led(ledCounter).Left = VB6.TwipsToPixelsX(15)
  Led(ledCounter).Height = VB6.TwipsToPixelsY(LedHeight)
  Led(ledCounter).Width = VB6.TwipsToPixelsX(LedWidth)
  Led(ledCounter).BorderStyle = Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.None
  Led(ledCounter).BackColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromOle(LedColor)
  Led(ledCounter).Visible = True
Next
```

Comment: And what could possibly explain the need for 3000 labels?

Answer (score 3):

In VB6, a label is a [windowless (lightweight) control](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/02/11/371042.aspx). It doesn't have a window handle and therefore does not exist as far as the OS is concerned. The code behind this control just checks where the mouse is and does some drawing on the parent control.

In VB.NET, however, a label is a full-fledged control that has a window handle and therefore "exists." Creating several thousands of these is a bad idea, because [number of available window handles is limited](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/07/18/3926581.aspx) (and because it's slow).

You should revise your design and consider using a grid of some sort.

Comment: Or drawing your own windowless controls. Inherit from `Control` and use the `Graphics` class to do all the drawing you need. Then you'll only have one control (window handle).

Comment: Cody Gray, Thanks for your answer, can you please elaborate it.

Comment: @sardar: I'm not sure how else to elaborate. You're essentially creating a custom control. If you're not sure how to do that, there's a lot more to it than I can describe in a comment. Search for a book on creating custom controls in .NET WinForms. Essentially, with a custom control, where you manage all the drawing yourself, you will only have one window handle, but can draw whatever you want. Unless you really need extensive customization, GSerg's solution of using a ready-made control is a much better option. Check out the `DataGridView`, `ListView`, `TreeView`, etc.

Comment: @GSerg Is there any windowless (lightweight) control in vb.net that can be used

Comment: @sardarCoder No. .NET gave up on the idea. `Control`, the base class for all controls, already is a window.

Comment: @GSerg is there any available control for simulation of LED board display.

Comment: @sardarCoder Maybe there is, I'm just not aware about them. You can try googling. Or you can easily write your own LED display using, as Cody Gray suggested, a custom control. You'd have an array or `Rectangle`s in that control and draw them using `Graphics.DrawRectangle`.