# vb.net LED BOARD DISPLAY user control

Tags: vb.net, image, vb6-migration, led, system.drawing.imaging

I am developing LEDBOARD user control in vb.net.I have done it also .Actually its taking too much time to load .In the **vb6** same application I am loading 3000 labels using a label control array but not time consuming .In **vb.net** I am doing same but it's taking too much time to load 3000 labels.**Is there any other way(any control or any custom control) to draw input text(any font style),image like below image**
     It looks like below[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [vb.net taking too much time to load user control containing Label control array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8601700/vb-net-taking-too-much-time-to-load-user-control-containing-label-control-array)

Comment: You [already asked this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8601700/vb-net-taking-too-much-time-to-load-user-control-containing-label-control-array). If you want to include additional details, you should edit that question to include them, not ask a new one.

Comment: @CodyGray yes sir its same problem but i want to explore it by using image so that i can get better idea to show same output using different ideas

Comment: It helps if you actually read what people say: *"If you want to include additional details, you should edit that question to include them, not ask a new one."*

Answer (score 1):

Create your LedBoard control from scratch by inheriting from `Control`, instead of using a UserControl and adding tons of labels.

I just made a little test to show you what I mean. You will have to adapt the logic to meet your needs.

```
Public Class LedBoard
    Inherits Control

    Private _rand As Random = New Random()

    Protected Overrides Sub OnPaint(ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs)
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Black, 0, 0, Width, Height)

        Const nx As Integer = 40, ny As Integer = 25

        Dim w = CInt((Width - 1) / nx) - 1
        Dim h = CInt((Height - 1) / ny) - 1
        For x As Integer = 0 To nx - 1
            For y As Integer = 0 To ny - 1
                If _rand.NextDouble() < 0.8 Then
                    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Red, x * (w + 1) + 1, y * (h + 1) + 1, w, h)
                End If
            Next
        Next

    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Note: All classes of the current solution inheriting from `Control` automatically appear at the top of the toolbox and you can drag them to a form.

Comment: Thank you Olivier Jacot-Descombes and cody gray .Actually i also came to solution same like you and output is much like above but only i am not getting lines which are separated like blockes.In above pictures there are 5 vertical lines and 1 horizontal line